# TAPI in ASP.NET webpage

Tags: vb.net, html, tapi

I am currently working on a project where I need to implement some sort of telephony services in a webpage. The project is written on VB.net and postback is disabled since clients dont want the page to be reloaded every time something happens. Server architecture is Windows 2012 R2 X64. Cant give you exact model of the modem but its normally USB/Serial data modems.

I have been reading articles/blogs on TAPI for the last few days. Many people have said it is impossible to integrate TAPI in a webpage but on Julmar.com i found a sample. (http://julmar.com/blog/programming/utilizing-tapi-from-an-asp-net-application/)

Now my questions are:

1. If above code works (which i havent tried yet) then how can i get incoming caller id without refreshing the page (possibly using jquery or some sort of script/activex)?
2. There will be only one modem connected to the network (possibly with the server PC) so is it possible to control the modem (including capturing caller id) from the client pcs?

I am going to share my own thinking so that you can suggest me if theres anything better. Since the project has already using SignalR so I can make a winform application to capture caller id and pass it to the connected clients through SignalR. But is it possible/wise to make and receive call via signalr?

Appreciate any help and should you require further information, please feel free to ask.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I have done 2 TAPI projects so far.

Your question is hard because it's not really a specific question. However I have made a similar service in VB.NET.

I'm now working on a service also.

Try looking into events like: 
MyTAPI.TE_CALLSTATE
MyTAPI.TE_CALLNOTIFICATION

A nice example:
https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/636769/VB-NET-ITAPI-TAPI-Incoming-call-and-caller-ID

No idea why you need modem stuff.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I will give a heads up when i find something